# copy protection

Tags: android, copy-protection

I am about to release my App.

I saw that there is a option copy protection provided by Google.
My App will be free.

So what is your suggestion? Should I use the copy protection? What are the benefits and what are the drawbacks using it.

Answer (score 0):

Main drawback: Google themselves advise you to not use it right next to where you enable it. Do you need anything else?

If you want some small semblance of protection, use ProGuard so a decompilation might be harder to read.

Comment: thx for answering. But why do they suggest not to use it? I know that it is broken already..